# How to implement Cascaded lookup in SP 2010?

Tags: lookup-column

In sp 2007, I have used jquery to do the cascade. But now I hear sp 2010 provides cascaded lookup. I have 3 level to drill down (Country > State > City). Is/are there any good instruction on how to implement cascaded lookup? All the lists have been created with parent-child relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) function within SPServices.

Comment: @That's Marc jQuery stuff right? which I used in SP 2007. Now that microsoft has a way to implement cascaded lookup i rather use that. I am tired of maintaining codeplex code + all the 3rd party stuff we have.

Comment: CascadeDropdowns works in both versions.  You shouldn't have to change anything if you've already implemented it in 2007.

Comment: Roxanne, The relational behavior you're describing in 2010 is limited to cascading delete, so if I delete my parent record I can set it up to automatically remove all of the child records of that record. You also have the ability to bring in multiple fields from a lookup, but it's not a cascade. The only way to cascade in a form is through UI changes such as using SPServices, you'd be doing the same thing as you did in 2007. There's some "for purchase" bolt-ons that make it "easier", but SPServices is most likely still your best bet.

Comment: Also (was out of characters in my previous comment), there's a good blog post here which explains the SP2010 relational stuff pretty well: http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/01/05/sp-2010-how-to-relational-lists-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Also, you should be able to do the cascade drop downs by modifying the forms in InfoPath.  I don't recall being able to do cascade dropdowns through the Sharepoint UI in 2010.

Comment: 1. I got the point cascade drop on edit form is different than enforce integrity between 2 lists. 
2. If I have to use the same method that I used in SP 2007 (with another company) then I can do that. 
3. I dont know why I made an assumption that MS now supports or give you cascade dropdown option for editform.
4. I will probably go with Marc's spservice to implement jQuery as it not as tightly coupled as Jose's solution (found here: http://blogs.solidq.com/sharepoint/Post.aspx?ID=86&title=Filtered+Lookup+Columns+for+Cascading+Dropdowns+in+SharePoint+2010+using+JavaScript+Client+Object+Model)

Comment: Roxanne: Always happy to answer questions about SPServices over at http://spservices.codeplex.com.  M.

Answer (score 2):

Read this article, which would help you in creating the cascading dropdowns in SharePoint
[Cascading or Filtered Lookup columns in SharePoint](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/02/cascading-dropdown-or-filtered-values.html)

[Cascading drop down in SharePoint using REST API (for SP 2013, 2016 versions & SP Online)](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2017/06/cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint.html)
Hope this helps you!