# Dependency between 2 choice columns

Tags: list, choice-field

I'm using SharePoint 2007.

I created a custom list.

In the list I create 2 choice fields (`column A`, `column B`).

I want to implement this scenario:
If the user chooses the first choice from column A, he sees in column B the choice 1,2,3.
If the user chooses the second choice from column A, he sees in column B the choice 4,5.

P.S. I do not have the permission to use the designer and the server.

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a filtered lookup field](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/how-to-make-a-filtered-lookup-field)

Comment: @PirateEric: Perhaps this has merit as an alternative entry-point for those that don't quite know what they're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing sounds like a Cascading Lookup. There are several existing questions with suggestions for implementing such a thing:

[How can we get Cascading Lookup Columns in sharepoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25535/how-can-we-get-cascading-lookup-columns-in-sharepoint-2010)

[How to implement Cascaded lookup in SP 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13030/how-to-implement-cascaded-lookup-in-sp-2010)

[How to make a filtered lookup field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/how-to-make-a-filtered-lookup-field)

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in functionality for this scenario.You have to write a custom javascript code to handle selection changes in the first dropdown and limit the selection in the second. And you need to have a full range of values (1,2,3,4,5) in the second column in order to save any entered value.