# NewForm.aspx WIth Lookup Conditional based on another lookup Field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, newform

I have Two Lists

List1 `{College Name, Department Name}`

And List2 `{Student Name , College (as lookup field link with College Name on List1) , Department(as lookup field link with Department Name on List1)}`

My requirement is creating NewForm.aspx for the List2 , but if I want to show on the ComboBox of lookup field (Department) Only Items with condition College= College.selected value

Is There anyway To do this By SharePoint Designer ?

Comment: Which is your sharepoint version?

Comment: office 365 small business plan , sharepoint 2013

Comment: You are looking for cascaded lookups: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25535/how-can-we-get-cascading-lookup-columns-in-sharepoint-2010 http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13030/how-to-implement-cascaded-lookup-in-sp-2010

Comment: is there anyway instead of cascaded lookups , because i have only two college and statics ( Computer , Languages ) , i want when user select Languages ,  show only the department of this college

Answer (score 1):

Edit the page in browser and add a Script Editor Webpart. Then

Next on page load bind change event of the college dropdown box as below

```
    //Replace C1 with the title of the combo box.
    $('[title="C1"]').bind("change", function() {
        bindDepartments($(this).val());
    });

    function bindDepartments(college) {
        //Replace C2 with the title of the department combo box
        $('[title="C2"]').empty();
        alert(college);
        //Load department using REST(filter) or JSOM (CAML)
    }
```

Comment: Is There any vedio learn how to do that please

Comment: You can just use google and use the words i put it on comment

Answer (score 1):

Look for SPServices on Codeplex.

https://spservices.codeplex.com/

The SPCascadeDropdowns function lets you set up cascading dropdowns on SharePoint forms. What this means is that you can enforce hierarchical relationships between column values. The function uses the GetListItems operation of the Lists Web Service to refresh the allowable values based on relationships which are maintained in reference lists. By implementing this function, there are no coding requirements to manage the hierarchical relationships (once it is in place) and you can let your users manage the content in the reference lists.

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Should you provide more details  with example

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `InfoPath`

- Open your list and from the above ribbon, select customizes it  via InfoPath.
- In the InfoPath form designer right click on Project field and click on Drop-Down list properties option.
- On the newly opened dialog click Add button
- You need to create new connection to receive data from Projects list. Select Create a new connection to: Receive Data. Click Next >..
- Select SharePoint library or list as your source. Click Next .
- Type in the URL of your SharePoint site. Click Next >.
- Select Projects list you create before. Click Next >.
- From the fields list, select the following fields: Title, and Active. Select to sort by Title. Click Next.
- Click Next button a few times to finalize this wizard. Once completed you will be taken back to properties dialog.
  Select ID field as value field. Click the button Next to Entries field, then Select a Field or Group dialog should appear.
- On the Select a Field or Group dialog click on Filter Data… button
- On the filter dialog, create a filter as shown on picture below. This will force drop down to load only active projects.

  - Check the details steps [here](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/2010/01/creating-filtered-lookups-in-sharepoint-2010-with-infopath-2010/comment-page-1/?rcommentid=56570&rerror=htmllang%3Den&rchash=82ce2b5bce640a1c475ec90688c513cf#commentform)
  - Check also this [vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSUSHsxsR6U)